# Docx4j - horizontal line missing while converting xhtml to docx using doc4j

Tags: java, xhtml, docx, docx4j

I am converting xhtml to docx using doc4j.
But the horizontal line that is present in xhtml is not being added to the docx. following is the snippet I am using. Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

```
String stringFromFile = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(dest

                + "/" + xhtmlFile), "UTF-8");
        WordprocessingMLPackage docxOut = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .createPackage();

        NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
        docxOut.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
        ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();
        XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(docxOut);
        XHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
        docxOut.getMainDocumentPart().getContent()
                .addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(stringFromFile, null));
```

Comment: Is the horizontal line an <hr/> element, or something else?

Comment: hi jason,yes its <hr/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This commit](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/commit/2bc482611f9cfb9e40f15a1311d99df71bb0388f) adds support for hr, using the same Open XML as Word 2010.